# Controlling an object using a functor : efficiency, modularity?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

Good evening,

Consider the following code :

```
class Controlled;

//============================================================================

class Controller {
public:
    explicit    Controller( Controlled* c ) : mControlled( c ) { }
    void        Update( const Time dt ) { /* do stuff */ }

    template<class T>
    void        Apply( T fn );

private:
    Controlled* mControlled;
};

template<class T>
void EntityController::Apply( T fn ) {
    fn( mControlled );
}

//============================================================================

class ControlledUpdate_f {
public:
    ControlledUpdate_f( const Time dt ) : mTime( dt ) { }
    void operator()( Controlled* c ) { /* do stuff */ }
private:
    Time mTime;
};
```

Of the two Update() fonctions, one part of the controller class and the functor one which is more efficient ? By how much ?
Secondly, is the functor system more modular than the other one ? I could see it doing very well using a scripting engine.

Thank you for your time. I apologize in advance if the question has an obvious answer.

Comment: Which is more important, efficiency, readability (maintenance), ease of change, size or robustness?  This will affect your answers.

Comment: Fair point. Efficiency is my primary concern ; however, I will willingly sacrifice some of it for a more robust system.

Comment: I would advise in favor of using the functor. It makes your system more flexible for different types of update algorithms. I don't think you are going go lose much in performance, if anything at all.